# What is the idiomatic way to truncate a string down to 100 byte-pairs?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cast, string

`nvarchar(100)` holds 100 **byte-pairs**, as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks). `LEFT([Your String], 100)` truncates your string down to 100 **characters** as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). These are not the same.

Foolishly, I have used `LEFT([Your String], 100)` in the hopes of keeping `[Your String]` within `nvarchar(100)`. What are the idiomatic approaches to solving this problem correctly? I considered using `CAST`, but I'm uncomfortable with implicitly truncating a string.

Comment: In a single sentence, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @J.D. How do I truncate a string to fit inside `nvarchar(100)`?

Comment: Depends on what part of the string you want truncated. You always want the first 100 byte pairs of the string (reading from left to right)?

Comment: `CAST` is the best way probably https://stackoverflow.com/a/77394718/73226

Comment: @J.D. Yes. In an ideal world, I'd have `LEFT` but for byte pairs.

Comment: @MartinSmith That seems to assume that I'm using a _SC collation?

Comment: It is about `varchar` and `UTF-8`. If you aren't using an `SC` collation then under what circumstances will `LEFT` not do what you need for `nvarchar`?

Comment: @MartinSmith I'm under the impression that 100 Chinese characters will fit in `LEFT([Your String], 100)` but won't fit in `nvarchar(100)` even in non-SC collations.

Comment: can you add such an example to your question? AFAIK the whole point of SC collations was to add support for characters that take more than one byte pair

Comment: @MartinSmith I suppose that I must be mistaken. I'll check on Monday. If you're right, then you've saved me some work. I would check on dbfiddle but that doesn't seem to like my unicode snowman or my Chinese characters.

Comment: The point I'm making is that in collations that aren't SC aware they don't support anything other than 2 bytes per character anyway. Are you talking about cases where double surrogate pairs (which represent a single character in encodings other than UCS-2) are inserted to an `nvarchar` without an `SC` aware collation anyway?

Comment: @MartinSmith Your point has proven correct. I'm in a non-SC collation, so `LEFT` is all that I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can be sure that `[Your String]` is using a non-SC collation, you can use `LEFT([Your String], 100)` and `CAST([Your String] as nvarchar(100))` interchangeably, since in non-SC collations each byte pair represents a character (surrogate characters represent themselves).

Whether or not `[Your String]` is using an SC collation (which it should be, if surrogate characters are to represent anything other than themselves), `CAST([Your String] as nvarchar(N))` will never perform a truncation in the middle of a byte sequence that represents a character (where the interpretation of such a byte sequence as a single character is determined by the current collation). You can confirm that by running the following code and inspecting its output.

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT 
      N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC [SC String],
      N'' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS [non-SC String]
)
SELECT 
    DATALENGTH(CAST([SC String] as nvarchar(1))) [SC DataLength],
    DATALENGTH(CAST([non-SC String] as nvarchar(1))) [non-SC DataLength]
FROM cte
```

In the general case, `CAST` is the way to go.

Comment: I think your CTE may need a second `SELECT` to demonstrate the behavior in non-SC collations.

Comment: You are right, @j-mini. I modified the code to demonstrate the behavior in non-SC collations.

Comment: This appears to be correct. However, the code block does not prove the first paragraph's point that `LEFT` is interchangeable with `CAST`.